# How To Call values from provider Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have this provider which retrieves data from a shared preference.

```
class AuthProvider with ChangeNotifier {
   String? usertoken = '';
   String? tokenExpiry = '';
  Future<AuthResponse> getuserdata() async {
    SharedPreferences _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String? userdata = _preferences.getString('userData');
    var usersData = jsonDecode(userdata!);
    AuthResponse authResponse = AuthResponse.fromJson(usersData);
    usertoken = authResponse.token;
    print('Test in provider : $usertoken');
    notifyListeners();
    return authResponse;
  }
}
```

How can i get the values i need from the provider? to say another function?

```
getinterestList() async {
    final test = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context).usertoken; //gets Error
    print(test);
  }
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Unhandled Exception: dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_InheritedProviderScope<AuthProvider>>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _InterestScreenState.initState() completed.

Comment: @EhsanAskari is this the correct way to fetch data from provider?

Comment: I think you calling it from ```initState```. if so wrap your code inside ```WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) { 
        ///your code here
    });```. Yes this is the correct way.